# Cannot install GLFW-b-0.0.2.10 package

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, glfw

When I do

```
cabal install GLFW-b
```

I get an error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package Cabal-1.10.1.0: 
    Cabal-1.10.1.0-49678efb6bfc399545e2b61629b900e2 is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:
      process-1.0.1.5-107ac5b78a5845608025ca13d328fdc5
    (use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
GLFW-b-0.0.2.10 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I am running the Haskell Platform 2010.2.0.0. Does anybody else get this? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haskell Platform version you're using included `Cabal-1.8.0.6`. The simplest solution should be to upgrade to the latest Haskell Platform which includes `Cabal-1.10.1.0`.

Comment: Thanks, it installed fine now!